# Change style of dynamically created elements in react

Tags: reactjs

I am pretty new to React and I have a requirement where I need to generate multiple div's and on button click I need to display those div's. Here is the code

```
    export default class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            dynaDiv: {}
        };
        this.onChangeFunc = this.onChangeFunc.bind(this);
        this.buildDynamicDivs = this.buildDynamicDivs.bind(this);
    }
    onChangeFunc(inputName) {
        const testId = "test"+(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(10)));
        console.log(testId);
        console.log(this.state.dynaDiv[testId].display);
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            console.log(prevState.dynaDiv[testId]);
            return({
                ...prevState,
                dynaDiv: {
                    ...prevState.dynaDiv,
                    [testId]: {
                        ...prevState.dynaDiv[testId],
                        display: prevState.dynaDiv[testId].display == "none"?"":"none"
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
    buildDynamicDivs() {
        let divs = [];
        for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
            const dydiv = "test"+i;
            this.state.dynaDiv[dydiv] = {display: "none"}
            divs.push(<div key={i} id={dydiv} style={{display: this.state.dynaDiv[dydiv].display}}>Test div{i}</div>);
        }
        return divs;
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => this.onChangeFunc("username")}>Toggle</button>
                <button onClick={() => console.log("State: ", this.state)}>State</button>
                { this.buildDynamicDivs() }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So when user click on Toggle, a randomly generated number between 1-9 should display/hide based upon it's previous state ( if previously displayed then hide else show).

Comment: What do you mean by display/hide based upon previous state? Can you elaborate your problem statement?

Comment: Hi @tarzen chung, I have updated my question. Basically there will be some 10 div's whose ID will be generated dynamically, these 10 div's are created in function buildDunamicDivs() later when user clicks on Toggle button onChangeFunc() will be called which will hide or show dynamically created div's.

Comment: If you want to toggle hide/show divs, where does random number comes into picture. I have created a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-hopper-80ob9) as per my understanding. This should give you some idea.